# Unresponsive card with Polish electronic ID

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, polish

I have inserted my polish ID with an electronic layer into my Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader, but `pcsc_scan` gives me following results:

```
Wed Mar 27 15:21:14 2019
 Reader 0: Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader 00 00
  Event number: 15
  Card state: Card inserted, Unresponsive card,
```

Do I need some kind of drivers for that?

Comment: All built-in readers I know of are only capable of reading contact-based smart cards (golden or silver square with 6 or 8 contacts), which does not seem to be the type Poland uses. *Card inserted* may simply mean a mechanical sensor; you can check this by putting the wrong end of a credit card into the reader.

Comment: True that. Note that some Dell's have cheapo Broadcom NFC readers as well nowadays. Those however can often not handle extended length, so functionality may still be limited. Usually dual interface readers prefer contact if you use the contact slot, otherwise the reader doesn't know which interface to use.